# How to specify task timeout in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a spark structured streaming application where every batch gets processed in a few seconds. Right now, the current batch is stuck with all tasks in `RUNNING` status from more than an hour.

How can I specify a timeout in Spark at task level to tell spark that it should retry if task is not completed within defined time?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: I have seen this happening with intermittently which is perhaps due to table locks on database side/deadlocks may be. As I know my batch is not going to take more than a minute then instead of waiting for hours, I would want spark to retry after certain time. I see one property regarding speculation where spark can retry the slow tasks on different executors but I am looking if there can be an explicit timeout for task

Comment: Speculation is not really good use case. In certain cases, on spark let's say your cluster is busy and due to that you're unable to get executors for your job. At that time also, speculation may affect. So, beware of that but you can use speculation. It's just that you're not sure how to fine tune it. It could be network that can trigger speculation.

Comment: My tasks are in RUNNING status, So I was wondering a timeout which considers the time it has spent in running state(after getting exectuors assigned)

Comment: are you looking for this https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#networking ?

Comment: are you looking for [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#networking) ?

Comment: Thanks, I am not looking for network specific timeouts but a generic timeout for task to retry when it breaches threshold due to any reason

Comment: @conetfun Did you find solution for this? I also facing similar issue and I need timeout for this.

Comment: I couldn't find any solution for this